# I'm agreeing with you but

Tags: grammar

Good morning,in what circumstances could I use "I'm agreeing with you" instead of "I agree with you" in a conversation, a debate (animated for example)?

Comment: You may not be aware of the existence of our sister site “English Language Learners” which would seem more appropriate to questions like this, and where I imagine answers already exist.

Answer (score 2):

You could use it if you were interrupted by the other person while making a statement which broadly supported their expressed point of view but which, part way through, they thought was a disagreement.

For instance they might say

> I don't believe that the Earth is flat

you might be about to reply

> It looks flat but that's only because its diameter is so large

and they might interrupt after you've said "flat" by saying something like

> That doesn't prove that it is, I say it's round

At that point you might say

> I'm agreeing with you, but you didn't let me finish my sentence.

This is in contrast to

> I think the Earth is flat

> I *agree* with you.

In that case to say

> I'm *agreeing* with you

would not be grammatically correct, although it does occur in some dialects, particularly South Asian ones.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I heard this in a debate on LBC (native speakers of English). This was a debate about the 2020 Olympics, I'm agreeing with you but (I understand your point of vue but...) or because it is a long debate the progressive "agreeing" appears?

Comment: Yeah, @ManuelDelpierre, it strikes me as almost a combination of the two things.  "I'm agreeing with you" definitely sets up a "but" in this conversational context.  E.g., Person A makes a point that he doesn't like a rule change in a sport.  Person B makes the counter-argument that the old rule was terrible.  Person A might respond by making a bunch of points in agreement with B, and sum up by saying, "... so, I'm agreeing with you that the old rule was bad, but I think the new rule is even worse."  A is characterizing what he has just been saying as agreeing with B.

Comment: Hi Cruthers, I've just noticed you had written "what he has just been saying", why didn't you say "what he has just said"?

Comment: @ManuelDelpierre He used "has been saying " because it is the present continuous and, therefore, agrees with the tense of "is categorizing". We can use the present tense to talk about the past in this way so long as  the context makes it clear that we ware talking about the past (historians do it quite a lot) but we shouldn't mix tenses in the same part of the discussion. For instance we _can_ say "Henry viii _is_ deperate for a male heir at this point" but we shouldn't follow that with "so he _had_ his marriage to Catherine annulled and  _married_ Anne Bolyn".

Answer (score 0):

The present continuous is used when the act of agreeing is/was underway, being emphasized, or being used to indicate a current realization.

> "I'm not **agreeing with you**, by the way," Andy said. "I just think what
> you're saying is funny and interesting in a way." *[The Best of
> Witness, 1987-2004](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Best_of_Witness_1987_2004/-b4LAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22I%27m%20not%20agreeing%20with%20you%22&dq=%22I%27m%20not%20agreeing%20with%20you%22&printsec=frontcover)* p.48.

*I don't agree with you...* also works here.

> Being aware of this reality makes it clear why the libertarian focus
> should be on responsibility first and freedom second--like my dad said
> liberty should be. God, now I'm **agreeing with** my Dad. *[The Oxbow
> Revelation](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Oxbow_Revelation/dMPEwJgfIesC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22I%27m%20agreeing%20with*&pg=PA72&printsec=frontcover)* (2014) p.72

*Now I agree with my Dad* wouldn't convey a sudden realization, but rather a current state:  *I used to believe differently, but now I agree with my Dad.*

> So when we confess we **are agreeing with** the conviction of the Holy
> Spirit. We **are agreeing with** the heaven about us. We **are agreeing with**
> the testimony of the blood of Jesus. *[Father, Friend, and Judge](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Father_Friend_and_Judge/uizXDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22we%20are%20agreeing%20with%22&pg=PT171&printsec=frontcover)*
> (2020)

Present continuous to match a time duration (*When we confess...*).

> A head nodding “yes” doesn't mean the buyer **is agreeing with** you: it
> means they **are agreeing with** what they are thinking.
> *[Conversations That Sell](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22they%20are%20agreeing%20with%22&biw=1110&bih=642&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALeKk03wIlCwKim3zTyIUC_5CWhvqftOXQ%3A1627912083496&ei=k_cHYYnEHc_WtAaE_Jy4Ag&oq=%22they%20are%20agreeing%20with%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...7934.8911.0.9074.5.5.0.0.0.0.78.373.5.5.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.MHPq52X6Ij0)* (2013) p.164

Referring to the act of nodding and what it signifies *while it occurs*. Here *...doesn't mean the buyer agrees with you* also works; however, the simple present describes the buyer's *state* of being in agreement.

Comment: Thanks for your reactions. It was important and I think there are good points, apart for the ongoing explanation, the classic one. Why do think this progressive form has evolved in non progressive relevance, like here for example?